# Recurrence relation for algorithm that has 2 different recursive calls

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

Doing a problem on my HW, don't want to get too specific to avoid cheating.

When the algorithm calls itself there are two options

```
if (statement)
  return 1 + functionCall
else
  functionCall
```

So I'm writing the recurrence relation

If the statement is true then: T(n) = 1 + T(n-1)

Else: T(n) = T(n-1)

How do I write the recurrence relation if it's always different? do I just use a variable as a const? So it would be T(n) = c + T(n-1)?

Comment: This recursion has no base case and will not terminate. Are you sure this accurately represents your problem?

Comment: There is usually a degenerate case e.g. in recursive factorial functions, if (n==0) return 1; This terminates the chain of recursive calls.

Comment: The function can have more than one parameter $f(n,c)$ :
if (statement) return c + f(n-1,c-1); else return f(n-1,c-1); or whatever you want to do with c in the second parameter.

Comment: This is just a snippet of the algorithm, I see how this might have been misleading. It does terminate at n == 0.

Comment: @JustBeCoo Usually you don't want to exactly compute $T(n)$ but rather have bounds on it. So in your example $T(n)\leq T(n-1)+1$ should do the job. You will get $T(n)=O(n)$ if you are familiar with the big O notation.